# ComboBox list throgh Range in sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

In userform I inserted ComboBox and i have to add list through Array following are the code. I want that whether it is possible that in ComboBox list will get from a Range in sheet (like in case of Data Validation)

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    ComboBox1.List = Array("Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the range in the sheet to create, even a named range, e.g.:

```
combobox1.list = range(cells(1,1),cells(100,1)).value

combobox2.list = sheets(1).range("NamedRange")

arr = array("1","2","3")
combobox3.list = arr
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you'd use a range to set the row source of a combo box. You can also do this in vba.

```
Me.combobox1.RowSource = "MyRange"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Doug Coats

Comment: Anytime. Remember to mark as answered to the answer that helped you answer your question.

Comment: When I saw this answer, my first reaction was "Why not put the list in a Table and point to that table?".  So I gave it a try.  The first time I ran the form, it worked like a charm.  Then I added a couple of values to the table, ran the form again and crashed Excel. I was able to repeat this twice, so I think that I may have found yet another bug in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this to a Table (ListObject) instead of a static range.  Create a Table with your list of values, instead of just using a static range of cells.  This way when you need to add to the list, you simply enter the new values, which are added to the Table. In my example, I have a Table named "Table1" and a column with the heading "Numbers".  Then call this function:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ComboBox1.RowSource = "=Table1[Numbers]"
End Sub
```

You have to do this on the Iniitalize, since setting the RowSource from the ComboBox Properties will cause Excel to crash the first time you add an item to your list.

This gives you a list that you can edit without having to edit the code behind the UserForm.